# A linear function that returns 8096 when x is 8, and returns 1024 where x is 65536

Tags: linear-algebra, graphing-functions

I'm struggling to come up with a formula that returns 8096 when x is 8 and 1024 when x is 65536. And appropriately returns the correct y when x is between those values. I think this is a simple graph equation problem but I'm struggling to come up with something nice!

Thanks a lot

Comment: First, compute the slope of this line. Then, use [point-slope form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_equation#Point%E2%80%93slope_form)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You start with a general approach for linear functions
$$
f(x) = mx + b.
$$
You want
$$
f(8) = m\cdot 8 + b = 8096
$$
and
$$
f(65536) = m\cdot 65536 + b= 1024.
$$
This gives you a linear system of equations
$$
8m + b = 8096\\
65536 m+ b =1024
$$
which you want to solve for $m$ and $b$.
Now $\frac{65536}{8192}=8$ so this is equivalent to

$$
8m + b = 8096\\
8 m+ \frac{1}{8192}b =\frac 1 8
$$

now subtract one equation from the other. That leaves you with an equation only involving $b$ which you can therefore solve for $b$. Now plug this value in either of the two equations above and solve for $m$. Now since you know $m$ and $b$ you found your desired function.

Comment: amazing explanation - thanks so much!